# WebScriptObject from NSObject

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, webkit, web-scripting

I'm using `WebScripting` resp. `WebScriptObject` to have communicate from my WebApp to an ObjC interface and vice-versa.

I can also call methods on JS objects. This works great. Any returned object is converted to ObjC types like `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Now I want to SEND an object. In JavaScript I would do it like this:

```
external.processDict({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
```

But how can I do that using ObjC? The docs say:

```
/*!
    @method callWebScriptMethod:withArguments:
    @param name The name of the method to call in the script environment.
    @param arguments The arguments to pass to the script environment.
    @discussion Calls the specified method in the script environment using the specified arguments.
    @result Returns the result of calling the script method.
    Returns WebUndefined when an exception is thrown in the script environment.
*/
- (id)callWebScriptMethod:(NSString *)name withArguments:(NSArray *)arguments;
```

This does not help at all. The `arguments` is an array of "arguments to pass to the script environment". The *Documentation* says "The values to pass to the method".

As ***WHAT***?! Apples? Bananas? `NSObject` or what kind of whatever?

When I pass a dictionary (for example the one that I received using WebScripting protocol) then I get an empty object of type `ObjCRuntimeObject` with no values and no keys.

So how do I send arrays and/or dictionaries to the environment?

What I tried so far:

```
+ (id)_parseObject:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        return [self webScriptObjectForArray:object];
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return [self webScriptObjectForDctionary:object];
    }
    else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
        return [object stringValue];
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object];
}

+ (WebScriptObject *)webScriptObjectForDctionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    dictionary = [dictionary copy];
    WebScriptObject *object = [[WebScriptObject alloc] init];

    for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        [object setValue:[self _parseObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]] forKey:key];
    }

    return object;
}

+ (WebScriptObject *)webScriptObjectForArray:(NSArray *)array {
    array = [array copy];
    WebScriptObject *object = [[WebScriptObject alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        [object setValue:[self _parseObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(i)]];
    }

    return object;
}
```

But I cannot set object values of that `WebScriptObject`, I'm always getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

**EDIT I**

I discovered using `NSArray` I get an array. So how working with dictionaries?